# Email send but not received in python

Tags: python, email

I have tried a simple email script in python to understand the functioning. The code is

```
import smtplib
sender = 'avin@gmail.com'
receivers = ['avin.b@vipointsolutions.net']
message = "This is a test e-mail message."

try:
smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')    
smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
print("Successfully sent email")
except Exception:
print("error")
```

When i try to run this i got the message `Successfully sent email` but the email is not delivered to my inbox.I have set up postfix running on my local machine at port 25.Can anyone guide me with the reason on why the email is not receiving.Is it because of the code? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide **SMTP** of the email sender and you have to login from the sender email.

example:

```
sender = 'avin@gmail.com'
receivers = 'avin.b@vipointsolutions.net'
msg_format = "Hello, Test email"
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com')
            server.starttls()
            server.verify(receivers)
            server.login(sender, 'password')
            server.sendmail(sender, receivers, msg_format)
            server.quit()
print("Successfully sent email")
```

Comment: I have tried this code by using smtp.google.com and I have used my gmail password but when i run the code its still in running state and not showing any messages

Comment: SMTP server address of Gmail is `smtp.gmail.com` try with this.

Comment: @i tried it but still the issue persists.The program isnt showing any error.It is just in process state but the email is not receiving on my receipent inbox